# What is a simple example of using Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber

The docs at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Step-Definitions are great and have tons of detail.  They're a bit overwhelming for a newbie to cucumber.
I just want to understand how my englishy spec will relate to the code it will execute and what files to put where.  What is a  high level summary of that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this spec:

```
Feature: Buy car

  Scenario: Jeff buys a car
    Given Jeff sees a car he want
    And he has the cash
    When he pays cash
    Then Jeff should own the car
```

The above spec file is called `buy_car.feature` and is placed in `/spec/features/`

The steps (Given, When, Then) inside `Scenario: Jeff buys a car` will reference the ruby file `spec/features/step_definitions/buy_car_steps.rb` which will have content like this:

```
Given("Jeff sees a car he wants") do |car|
  perform capybara action to display car, e.g. visit, click, etc.
end
When("he pays cash") do |pay|
  perform payment actions (front or back end as desired)
end
And("he has the cash") do |cash_check|
  perform code to check bank balance is sufficient
end
...
```

I think this is right for where stuff goes and how it is named but welcome review and any correction.  I've always found the cucumber docs a little hard to get started with so wanted to help with another simple example for folks getting started.